# Nginx folder is not getting redirected

Tags: url, nginx

My nginx is running a php Laravel application. Now it is running at 192.x.x./public/..

How can i change it to 192.x.x.x/helpdesk/public/
I tried many things in the nginx config files by pointing the root directory accordingly by creating the helpdesk folder but still it doesn't work

Comment: Please provide us with some more information. What exactly doesnt work. What is the expected result vs. what are you getting. And please give us the config you are working with.

Comment: Currently when i run the url domain(or ip) it redirects to my nginx and shows up the page. But what i need is to run like domain or ip/helpdesk/..

Comment: I mean the url need to be like that

Comment: Is there anyone to help me?